# Multiplying any matrices

Tags: matrix

I am currently having trouble with my "multiplying matrix" code. The goal of the code is to take a matrix from one text file and multiply it with a matrix from another text file. When the multiplication is done, the results have to be printed in a new text file. My code (below) is works well with multiplying the matrices below:

the first matrix:
[image: matrixA]

The second matrix:
[image: matrixB]

The printed out answer (which is correct):
[image: matrixAnswer]

My problem is that my code cannot answer (or even complete) the matrix below:

matrixA:
[image]

matrixB:
[image]

It will just spit out an error like: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3 at MM.main(MM.java:56)"

my code (below):
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MM {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
int x, y, z, rows=1000, col = 1000;
    int[][] matrixA = new int[rows][col];
    int[][] matrixB = new int[rows][col];


//here we will read through the first txt file, that being matrixA.txt
  Scanner s1 = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("matrixA1.txt")));

//next, we make sure the that the rows and columns of the first matrix is set at zero (creating new variables)
int r = 0, c = 0;

//Next, we will use a while loop so that we can interate through the txt file with the matrixes
while(s1.hasNextLine()){
    String[] str = s1.nextLine().trim().split(" "); //this will make sure to look past the space essentially
    
    for(x = 0; x < str.length; x++){
        matrixA[r][x] = Integer.parseInt(str[x]); //this will convert the string into an integer
    }
    c = x;
    r++;
}

//Now we will read from the second txt file (that being matrixB.txt file)
Scanner s2 = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("matrixB1.txt")));

int r1 = 0, c1 = 0;

//Just like with matrixA.txt file, we will be also scanning through the file so that we can read each line
while(s2.hasNextLine()){
    String[] str1 = s2.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
    
    for(x = 0; x < str1.length; x++){
        matrixB[c1][x] = Integer.parseInt(str1[x]);
    }
    r1 = x;
    c1++;
}

if(c == c1){
// here we are going to be creating the new matrix columns
    int[][] nc = new int[r1][r];
    for(x = 0; x<r; x++){
        for(y = 0; y<r1; y++){
            nc[x][y] = 0;
            for (z = 0; z < c1; z++){
                nc[x][y] = nc[x][y] + matrixA[x][z] * matrixB[z][y];
            }
        }
    } 


//first we will check to see can the two matrixes even multiply

if (matrixA[0].length != matrixB.length) {
    System.out.println("Unable to perform matrix multiplication.");
    return;
}


//Lastly, we will make a new file that will contain the answer in it
BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("matrixAnswer.txt"));

//we will be printing nc matrix to the new file
for(x = 0; x < r; x++){
    for(y = 0; y < r1; y++){
        bfw.write(Integer.toString(nc[x][y]));
        if (y < r1 - 1) {
            bfw.write(" ");
        }
    }
    if(x < r - 1){
        bfw.newLine();
    }
}
bfw.close();
}
```

}
}

Comment: Hi @Rayman , Can you paste code instead of images

Comment: You are using the wrong indices while reading `matrixB`. You are using `matrixB[c1][x]` instead of `matrixB[r1][x]`.